# rake db:create Not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

When i execute "rake db:create" command, I got following Errors

```
/home/shamithc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant MAJOR

/home/shamithc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant MINOR

/home/shamithc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant BUILD

/home/shamithc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant NUMBERS

/home/shamithc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:9: warning: already initialized constant VERSION

/home/shamithc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake.rb:26: warning: already initialized constant RAKEVERSION

/home/shamithc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/early_time.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant EARLY

/home/shamithc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: warning: already initialized constant WINDOWS

/home/shamithc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:28: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_RAKEFILES

WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#ext already exists
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#pathmap already exists
/home/shamithc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task_arguments.rb:73: warning: already initialized constant EMPTY_TASK_ARGS

/home/shamithc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/invocation_chain.rb:49: warning: already initialized constant EMPTY

/home/shamithc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:10: warning: already initialized constant RUBY

/home/shamithc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:84: warning: already initialized constant LN_SUPPORTED

/home/shamithc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:143: warning: already initialized constant Commands

/home/shamithc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:44: warning: already initialized constant ARRAY_METHODS

/home/shamithc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:47: warning: already initialized constant MUST_DEFINE

/home/shamithc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:51: warning: already initialized constant MUST_NOT_DEFINE

/home/shamithc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:55: warning: already initialized constant SPECIAL_RETURN

/home/shamithc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:61: warning: already initialized constant DELEGATING_METHODS

/home/shamithc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:364: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_IGNORE_PATTERNS

/home/shamithc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:370: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_IGNORE_PROCS

/home/shamithc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake.rb:64: warning: already initialized constant FileList

/home/shamithc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake.rb:65: warning: already initialized constant RakeFileUtils

rake aborted!
stack level too deep
/home/shamithc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25
```

How can resolve this problem .....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `rake` version bundled with your Ruby version is conflicting with the `rake` gem. Uninstall rake gem by doing

```
$ gem uninstall rake -a
```

Then execute the command again.

Comment: Or run rake with `bundle exec`

Comment: yes, Thanks for replay... its correct. After reinstalling rake it working.What is the reason for the above error.....