# Very strange thing with Rails 3 and Gettext (fast_gettext), undefined method 'add' for String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-3, gettext

I'm running on Rails 3.1.1 and ruby 1.9.2 on Mac OS and just started a new project where I want to use gettext for translations.

I followed every step when using fast_gettext described here: https://github.com/grosser/gettext_i18n_rails

The installation and everything works find. But when I try to rake gettext:find I get this error message:

```
$ bundle exec rake gettext:find
rake aborted!
undefined method `add' for "/Users/Olaf/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0":String

Tasks: TOP => gettext:find
```

I also have to use bundle exec when performing any kind of rake task, I have the problem described here:

[rake db:create Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227017/rake-dbcreate-not-working)

Maybe that is related.

Has anyone an idea what is going on? I'm a bit desperate, sitting here since hours trying to figure it out. Google doesn't deliver any hints.

**Thanks!**
Olaf

Answer (score 3):

I was having similar issues. I believe it comes down to an incompatibility between `gettext` and more recent versions of RubyGems (1.8+). There is a [pull request](https://github.com/mutoh/gettext/pull/11) that addresses this issue, but unfortunately it hasn't been merged yet.

In the meantime you can try adding the fork (and the commit that resolves the issue) as a dependency in your Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem 'gettext',      git: 'https://github.com/cameel/gettext.git', ref: 'c3a8373'
  gem 'ruby_parser'
  gem 'locale'
end
```

Comment: @grosser's hotfix:   
module Gem;def self.all_load_paths;[];end;end

Comment: @SurakarnSamkaew that would also be an option, if you don't mind monkey patches. I hope this is fixed upstream soon though.

Answer (score 0):

Install
 gem 'gettext', '>=3.0.2'

As it is specified on https://github.com/grosser/gettext_i18n_rails#optional